# what are the independent and the dependent variables to establish the test i need for hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictor

The data looks like this 
[image]

Actually the dataset has 4 levels, each level being a roll up of the original dataset A <- being rolled at a separate levels

A - original 
B - clubbed all products for each month
C - clubbed 3 months
D - clubbed 3 months and all products

The number of people are more than one and products may differ across people.

My question to be answered is whether there is a difference in performance before and after an event.

What are my independent and dependent variables in this case for each dataset i.e. A, B , C , D?

I know that  my dependent variables are the 2 achievements that i have.

My main problem in understanding the independent variables stems from the fact that the data is not at the same level. as in all the product are not same across everyone.

Should i do the analysis for all months, for all people having the same products?

In short i want to determine the test needed to perform hypothesis testing where my hypothesis looks like 
H0 = mu1 - mu2 = 0 
Ha1 = mu1 - mu2 not equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "event" is some experimental condition that is modified by the product usage. Furthermore, it looks like you are interested in the pre-post differences in achievement following being subject to the event, so your "outcome" would be the difference of the two achievements and the "predictor of interest" or "experimental condition of interest" would be a categorical effect for the type of product usage. Basically, if you create an "achievement difference" outcome, it is a simple ANOVA. Or, a more robust approach would be an ANCOVA adjusting for pre-event achievement as a predictor.

Furthermore, it looks like you have some repeated measures within subject and also over time. Therefore, you'll need to add some mild sophistication to this model, either a repeated measures ANOVA or other type of mixed effects model would suffice.

Comment: Actually the event is a qualitative aspect and not modified by product usage. The data has the person, products and the month because the achievements can be calculated only for that level of data. since there is no month achievement or only product achievement but achievement for a person for a product in a particular month. Also if i were to create a achievement difference column what would be my  "mu1" and "mu2" since my null hypothesis will be like the one in the question i.e. mu1 - mu2 = 0

Comment: @plv please review https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info for advice on how to better frame your question for a sufficient answer